# Error "Could not find the correct Provider<AppThemeNotifier> above this Consumer<AppThemeNotifier>"

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm currently working on a Flutter app and I have some issue to write tests.

When I run my test I have the following exception :
"The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Consumer(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Consumer
Widget"

This is a piece of my main.dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    themeData = Theme.of(context);
    return Consumer<AppThemeNotifier>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, AppThemeNotifier value, Widget? child) {
        customAppTheme = AppTheme.getCustomAppTheme(value.themeMode());
        return MultiBlocProvider(
            providers: [
              BlocProvider<AuthentificationBloc>(
                create: (context) => AuthentificationBloc(),
              ),
              BlocProvider<RegisterBloc>(
                create: (context) => RegisterBloc(),
              ),
              BlocProvider<EventsBloc>(
                create: (context) => EventsBloc(),
              ),
              BlocProvider<UsersBloc>(
                create: (context) => UsersBloc(),
              ),
            ],
```

And this is the test that I try to run

```
void main() {

Widget skeleton(widgetToTest)
{
  return Consumer<AppThemeNotifier>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, AppThemeNotifier value, Widget? child) {
        return widgetToTest;
      });

}

  testWidgets('My login page contains two textfield to enter my credentials',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(skeleton(Login2Screen()));

    final textFormFieldFinder = find.byElementType(TextFormField);

    expect(textFormFieldFinder, findsNWidgets(2));

  });
}
```

I tried to create the "skeleton" function to add the Provider but it doesn't work...

Any help is really appreciate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load `AppThemeNotifier` via `ChangeNotifierProvider` or any other suitable provider.

```dart
await tester.pumpWidget(
  ChangeNotifierProvider<AppThemeProvider>(
    create: (context) => AppThemeProvider(),
    child: skeleton(Login2Screen()),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, now I have another exception, the same than before but with my Authentication bloc class, see the exception below
`Could not find the correct Provider<AuthentificationBloc> above this
BlocBuilder<AuthentificationBloc, AuthentificationState> Widget`